# Get value of a Dictionary or HashTable based on a hash

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have a `Dictionary` where the keys are objects which are expensive to create. To avoid creating this objects every time I do a search, I have written a function to generate the hash of the object without actually creating it. The problem is, I would like to use the generated hash to search in the `Dictionary`, but `Dictionary` doesn't expose such a method (`HashTable` doesn't either).

Is it possible to do what I want?

#### Example

```
var dict = new Dictionary<ExpensiveObj, int>();
int i = dict.FindValueWithHash(generateHash()); // This is what I am looking for
```

Comment: 2 different objects can have the same hashcode. Your approach can't work because of this.

Comment: It would be still possible to check if there is more than one element. Only then I would create the object. In all the other cases I would save time.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the point? If the hashcode is in the dictionary then you still don't know if it's the same object. And if it's not in it then you still have to create it. At most I suppose you could try to retrieve a collection of all objects with that hashcode but 1) There is no such method as far as I'm aware and 2) You'll have to see if that is still profitable then

Comment: Jeroen is correct. Hashes are not meant to be unique. They're meant to be well distributed. Hashtables store items in buckets that can be rebalanced at any time. If collisions exist (eg more than one item exists in a bucket, not that it has the same hashcode), disambiguating a collision requires a search of all items in the bucket, using the equality members of the object. Take time to understand exactly how hash tables work. A custom implementation might save you a bit of processing, but it sure doesn't exist out of the box.

Comment: _"To avoid creating this objects every time I do a search"_ _Why_ do you need to create them always if they are sitting in the dictionary. You can store and reuse the dictionary. Of course `ExpensiveObj` needs to override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` or you have to write a custom `IEqualityComparer<ExpensiveObj>` for the [dictionary constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IEqualityComparer`, supplied to the constructor, and use "cheap" algorithm internally to handle a "cheap pseudo-key" as applicable.<sup>1</sup>

Look at the objects supplied - one will be a real object from the Dictionary, the other the "new"/pseudo-key object - to decide how to act. The pseudo-key object will have to conform to the same type as the key to avoid a type error (go interfaces!), but can itself be "cheap to create".

Both the hash code generation *and* equality must be handled appropriately - otherwise a false-positive (ie. duplication hash) can result.

Or change the algorithm/data-structure so that such an approach is not required.

---

<sup>1</sup> If a pseudo-key object always honors `pseudo.Equals(real) == real.Equals(pseudo)` and `pseudo.GetHashCode() == real.GetHashCode()`, such that the operations are "cheap" in all cases, then the custom comparer can be skipped as it would then merely bypass correct default behavior.

Comment: Go go interfaces indeed. Create a "mock" object that satisfies the same interface. Yay. +1